# Equipment for lower chest at home

Tags: workout, chest

I want to show up more lower chest.This is my problem.What equipments (start from cheapest) will be great at home that will give me results to show more my lower chest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To target the lower part of the chest, you want to focus on a declined angle during your exercises.

If you have no equipment, you can do push-ups with your feet on the floor and your hands on a higher platform, like such:

[image]

If you have some dumbbells, you can do dumbbells presses while you lie on an decline, elevating the lower part of the body. Like such:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do dips (you push down instead of in front of you so the angle hits your lower chest more than other exercises), you can do them on [rings](https://youtu.be/7AhIZkvQCwk), which are cheap are really really versatile, you can hang them from a pullup bar on from a tree or anything really

I think [pseudo-planche pushups](https://youtu.be/odcPqBOlJhI) should also target your lower chest since the forward lean angle puts your arms in the same positon relative to your body as in the elevated pushups or decline bench press. Cues:
- Putting your hands sideways, lean forward with a straight body until your shoulders are in front of your hands. Perform a pushup while maintaining forward lean. Protract the shoulderblades at the top.
- Increase forward lean to make more difficult. Decrease forward lean to make easier. You won't run out of resistance anytime soon if you keep increasing your forward lean.

You should check out https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/kb/recommended_routine if you want more info on how to work out at home with minimal equipment